# Removing image <a> link from specific page IDs or page slug in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, wordpress-hook

I need to remove links from images on my page, but only on specfic pages, or remove all the links all over the website, except a few page id's or page slugs.

I have the code for removing links, but I can't add to the exceptions:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );

function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    $content =
        preg_replace(
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
                '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
            array('<img','" />'),
            $content
        );
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Wordpress conditional function `is_page()`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );
function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    // Set your exception pages in here
    if( !is_page( array( 42, 48, 55 ) ) ) {
        $content = preg_replace( 
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
                '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
            array('<img','" />'),
            $content
        );
        return $content;
    }
}
```

You can use page IDs or page slugs like `"contact-us"`…

*---- ( updated adding a missing* `)` *in* `if( !is_page( array( 42, 48, 55 ) ) ) {` *) ----*

Comment: Thanks, but that example doesnt work for me, i have a bug when i paste it into my functions.php, can you check that code?

Comment: ok, i fixed this:

add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );

function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    // Set your exception pages in here
    if( !is_page( array( 42, 48, 55 ) ) ) {
        $content = preg_replace( 
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
                '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
            array('<img','" />'),
            $content
  ); }
        return $content;
    }

Answer (score 0):

More general than IDs [mentioned in LoicTheAztec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36938588/5623358) are eg. custom (meta) fields.

```
function bw_content($content)
{
    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'bw_remove_image_links', true) == 1) {
        $content = preg_replace(array(
            '{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
            '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'
        ), array(
            '<img',
            '" />'
        ), $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'bw_content');
```